# Views, adding I like, Retweet - best approach

Tags: views, 6

I have several views.

Now I need to add FB I like and retweet button to those views.

I search for modules, but all I get doesn't goes with Views well.

I would like to pass nid of node as excluded field and use Views Custom Field to create those links, but is this possible to get data from another field in custom field?

Answer (score 3):

I also searched for modules that would allow Social Sharing - what I ended up doing was just adding the code manually to the templates.  It's just a couple lines of javascript, usually.  I ended up using AddThis for the main group and then just pulled the Facebook like code from their website.

IMO, somtimes a module is overkill.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Now I see that only adding social links in custom JS script make sense.